# Foreach array - Neo4j

Tags: foreach, neo4j, cypher

I have this query and i have a problem with FOREACH:

```
MATCH (pc:car), (pa:parts)
With pc.car as CAR, collect(pa.name_parts) as parts_total
Foreach (i IN parts_total in CASE WHEN not (:car)-[:related_to5]->(:parts) is null then [1] else [0] END | Match (parts_total) Return parts_total)
Return *
```

i would like to have the value "0" for the elements of the arrays not connected to "car" and "1" for the elements instead connected.

Answer (score 0):

That query has numerous syntax errors. For example, you cannot have other clauses (like `MATCH`) in a `FOREACH` clause.

This should do what you want, fairly efficiently:

```
MATCH (pa:parts)
WITH COLLECT(pa) AS ps
MATCH (car:car)-[:related_to5]->(p:parts)
WITH ps, car, COLLECT (p) AS partsInCar
RETURN car,
  REDUCE (s = [], i IN ps |
    s + {part: i, value: CASE WHEN i IN partsInCar THEN 1 ELSE 0 END}) AS result
```